# Comics about a quantum labyrinth

Tags: story-identification, comics, quantum-physics

I am looking for a comic book I read when I was a child. I read it in my brother's collection of *Science et Vie Junior*, a French science popularization magazine (or its adult version *Science et Vie*). The magazine was releasing a few pages every month. I guess the story was also released in one or several volumes too. It appeared in the magazine during my brother's childhood, so during the 80's or at last the early 90's.

The comic book was Franco-Belgian style (I seem to remember a *Blake et Mortimer-ish* drawing style), and the author's name felt Italian. The story was about a young adult (late 20's, early 30's) lost in a strange labyrinth. I was like a scientific version of *Alice in Wonderland*. The main character had to go from one room to another, to discover a new test or trap, in a hope to finally get his freedom back. All of these were based on quantum mechanics or at least hard science (that's why it appeared in the science magazine).

I read only a few pages so I don't remember any other information. I know that this is quite tiny, but hopefully the context will help. *Science et Vie* is very famous in France and many of the French scientists that visit Stack Exchange regularly read it as child (and may still read it).

Comment: The question had been obsessing me for some time now. I will certainly offer a bounty as soon as I can.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The comic is part of [Aventures Quantiques](https://www.bedetheque.com/BD-Aventure-quantique-210340.html) by Sven Ortoli and Jean-Michel Pelhate.

This fits with the description as Sven Ortoli is the founder of *Science et Vie Junior* and is a PhD in Physics